# MySQL - SELECT INTO within a Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

We have a lot of stored procedures which have an `OUT` parameter which we are assigning a value to by using `SELECT LAST_INSERTID() INTO p_AutoNumber`.

After this, we need to perform another `INSERT` which also uses the value of this variable - however it doesn't appear to run correctly.

Does performing a `SELECT INTO` on an `OUT` parameter return from the procedure immedately? I am unable to find any information on this in the MySQL docs for `SELECT INTO`.

Comment: Select aValue INTO aVariable!

Comment: @krishKM I know! I mis-typed the command in the edit box, the SQL is correct though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the out-parameter within the procedure. Just check the syntax (and the function name):

Use syntax:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO p_AutoNumber;
```

Alternatively you can use syntax:

```
SET p_AutoNumber = LAST_INSERTID();
```